# Не загружается сессия в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Привет всем. При загрузке ubuntu появляется окно авторизации, ввод пароля, и все дела. После ввода пароля пропадает окно авторизации и тут должно появится рабочее окружение, но вместо этого ноут издает звук и выкидывает назад на окно авторизации. Если ввожу не правильный пароль, то оно так и пишет что "Неверный пароль". Через гостя тоже не заходит. Когда прохожу авторизацию через консоль(`Ctrl+Alt+F1`) то все нормально, могу выполнять различные команды.

Перед этим я ставил вот [это](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/bumblebee-xenial), потому что ноут сильно гудел (кулер) и т.д. Но есть плюс, ноут уже не гудит сильно, но работать за ним я не могу. Люди знающие, помогите новичку) А то уже запарился)

При заходе через любого пользователя все тоже самое. То есть это не из за пользовательских настроек.

Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus. Unity.

Вот что записано в файле `.xsession-errors` после неудачного входа:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2449) terminated with status 1
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: logrotate main process (2314) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_colord_colord-sane.113.crash) main process (2354) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_indicator-application_indicator-application-service.1000.crash) main process (2355) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2424) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2438) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2456) killed by TERM signal
upstart: job indicator-bluetooth failed to stop
```

После выполнения вот этих команд:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg 
sudo reboot
```

После перезагрузки - черный экран и мигает сверху слева в углу символ нижнего подчеркивания и все.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нет. не дубликат. тут выкидывает назад. а там просто был черный экран) то была проблема с экраном (монитором). а тут что то другое)

Comment: с вероятностью, значительно превышающей 50%, это ровно то же самое: пользовательские настройки, разбросанные по файлам/каталогам внутри домашнего каталога. проверяется элементарно — созданием нового пользователя и попыткой залогиниться от его имени.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ладно. если бы еще не заходило через мой акк. почему тогда через гостя тоже самое?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin при создании нового пользователя все тоже самое. не знаете как решить эту проблему?

Comment: начните с анализа ошибок в `~/.xsession-errors`. удалите этот файл, повторите попытку залогиниться, и анализируйте его после этого, обратив наибольшее внимание на последние строки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в вопросе я дописал что в том файле. посмотрите пожалуйста)

Comment: Через `recovery mode->resume` можете зайти?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего памяти не хватает на диске. Посмотрите сколько осталось места `df`. У меня такое было
Так же можно попробовать под `su`

```
mount -o remount, rw /
Xorg configure
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sync
reboot
```

Comment: используется 16% памяти.

Comment: а вот то что Вы второе написали там где `Xorg`, это на счет памяти?

Comment: @SkiesX Нет, это перенастройка иксов

Comment: Через `recovery mode->resume` можете зайти?

Comment: а как туда попасть? я новичок во всем этом(

Comment: @SkiesX Извиняюсь за задержку, при загрузке `BIOS` держите нажатым левый `shift`. Там будет дополнительные параметры -> `recovery mode`. И попробуйте для начала второй пункт, который я написал. Мне помогло в прошлый раз, как раз на этой системе и пишу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39740/discussion-between-skiesx-and-herrgott).

Comment: `startx` не сработало. написало что его нужно установить. установил. теперь после запуска команды `startx` сыпятся ошибки. может мне переустановить ubuntu или как это все можно решить мирным путем ?

Answer (score 1):

У меня имелась подобная проблема. Видеокарта Nvidia, наверное? Если так, то это проприетарный драйвер положил Unity. 
Зайдите по `Ctrl+Alt+F1` и введите вот что:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
```

Удаляем сам драйвер:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-xxx
```

где ххх - версия Вашего драйвера, которая install. Далее удаляем обновления:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates
reboot
```

Должно заработать.

PS Я после фокусов Bumblebee и OpenGL от греха переехала на KDE, потому что, судя по многочисленным отзывам, Nvidia и Unity никак не хотят уживаться.

Comment: да, это из за видеокарты, бамбелби не поддерживался, нужно было ставить nvidia-prime